# Unable to display username in emails with action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to do something extremely simple, which is display username on the registration email. However it's outputting a blank space instead of displaying the user. I have just setup ActionMailer and everything else I have done works fine.

Code from register template:

```
<%= @user.name %>,

Thank you for registering!
```

Code from user_mailer.rb:

```
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
```

Comment: Are you certain the user name attribute is actually "name" in the model and if so are you certain you aren't storing empty names in the database?

Comment: ah yes. All the medicine I'm on has me dope up. I haven't even got to the point of defining the username in the model yet. Have only done email so far with password of course lol. Thanks for the quick point out. Since I'm not using scaffold I keep forgetting I have to add this stuff myself lol.

Answer (score 0):

In to try something like this:

```
mail(:to => "#{user.name}<#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered")
```